# How to implement SIP packages in C#

Tags: c#, sip

> INVITE sip:john@domain.com SIP/2.0
>   From:
>   <sip:doe@domain.com>;tag=2084442460
>   To:  Via:
>   SIP/2.0/UDP
>   domain.com:5060;branch=z9hG4bK2df7b9194cd51e25
>   Call-ID: john@domain.com-4524j CSeq: 1
>   INVITE Contact:
>   <sip:doe@domain.com:5060>
>   Content-Length: 226 Content-Type:
>   application/sdp

I found this on the net. It seems to have those things that a packet has to have. How do I write a program in C# to send this packet?

I have to build a program that can do a call setup.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking? Are you looking for SIP help? or someone to write you your application?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! People will tend to be more willing to answer questions if the question is asked in a straightforward and readable fashion. Paying attention to things like capitalization, grammar, and punctuation can go a long ways towards convincing people that any answers they give are likely to be followed, and thus they are more likely to give them. Keep that in mind, and good luck finding the answer you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks, Jon B. Much more legible now.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I worked with the JAIN-SIP library in Java- I spent quite alot of time looking for a .Net equivalent but it seems SIP as a protocol is too old to be of any interest to .Net developers. I guess what im saying is, do you absolutely have to create this in C#?

If so, this document will help you - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt.

The packet you described above was the "INVITE" message- the first in a chain of messages. You invite a user, who will return with "OK" if they accept the invitation. After receiving this, send an ACK packet and then the two clients will be setup to comunicate. See the RFC for more information on the structure of these packets- what headers must be present, etc.